Is there a Baer's criterion for testing injectivity of sheaves of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules?
In the important paper by Spaltenstein on resolving unbounded complexes, they turn their hand to sheaves. Let us fix a ringed space $(X;\mathcal{O}_X)$. In the proof of Lemma $4.3$ it is implicitly asserted that:

The $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{J}$ is injective (in the category of $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules) if for all sheaves of ideals $\mathfrak{a}$, homomorphisms $\mathfrak{a}\to\mathscr{J}$ extend to homomorphisms $\mathcal{O}_X\to\mathscr{J}$.

If $X$ is just a point, then this is the usual Baer's criterion; this is then strictly generalising the classical case.
I'm struggling to mimic the usual proof. Let us assume $\mathscr{J}$ has this property, and take an inclusion of modules $\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{G}$, a homomorphism $\phi:\mathcal{F}\to\mathscr{J}$. By Zorn's lemma and some sheafification, I can find maximal data of a submodule $\mathcal{H}$ and map $\phi':\mathcal{H}\to\mathscr{J}$ containing and extending, respectively, $\mathcal{F}$ and $\phi$. If $\mathcal{H}\neq\mathcal{G}$, then they disagree on at least one open subset of $X$ and I can find a section $\sigma$ of $\mathcal{G}$ over some $U$ such that (i) $\sigma\notin\mathcal{H}(U)$ and (ii) $\sigma=\tau|_U$ only if $\tau=\sigma$, i.e. $\sigma$ cannot be further extended.
I'm considering $\mathcal{H}'$ the sheaf associated to the presheaf $P:V\mapsto\begin{cases}\mathcal{H}(V)&V\not\subseteq U\\\mathcal{H}(V)+\mathcal{O}_X(V)\sigma&V\subseteq U\end{cases}$; $\mathcal{F}\subseteq\mathcal{H}\subsetneq\mathcal{H}'\subseteq\mathcal{G}$ definitely holds, all being $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules.
Now here comes the real problem. $U$ need not be all of $X$. I cannot define a global multiply-by-$\sigma$ map $\mathcal{O}_X\twoheadrightarrow\mathcal{H'}/\mathcal{H}$, as I can in the classical case, and then consider the kernel ideal of this map. If I could, I think I could proceed. But I'm stuck at this juncture.
Does anyone have any ideas?

I’m not entirely sure, but from skimming through the argument it seems that you could just replace ideals with extensions by zeros of ideals and the proof would still work? Unless this is specifically discussed in the text earlier, I would (with much hesitation) bet on sloppiness.

@Aphelli So you mean something like, if for all sheaves of ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ of $\mathcal{O}_X|U$ over $U$, $U$ any open, we can extend maps along $(j_U)!\mathfrak{a}\hookrightarrow\mathcal{O}_X$?

I think this applies.

@Aphelli I think I have a workable version. Thanks for your suggestion which prompted me along the right lines; I would appreciate it if you could review my solution

As stated, I am not sure if the criterion is correct and it is plausibly false. However, a mildly amended statement holds - and applies, in the case of interest.
I also realised after the fact that Grothendieck got there already: in the proof of $1.10.1$ of the ‘Tohuku’ paper, a Baer criterion is offered for (something general which here specialises to) submodules of $\bigoplus_{U\subseteq X\text{ open}}\mathcal{O}_{U\subseteq X}$, this notation meaning the extensions by zero of the $\mathcal{O}_U$. This criterion also applies in my case of interest.
To be clear, I am not working with locally ringed spaces and I don't demand sheaf homomorphisms to be local homomorphisms. Just in case this conflicts with anything from geometry.

The $\mathcal{O}_X$-module $\mathscr{I}$ is injective iff. among all open $j:U\hookrightarrow X$ and all sheaves of ideals $\mathfrak{a}$ of $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X$, all $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X$-homomorphisms $\mathfrak{a}\to j^\ast\mathscr{I}$ extend to $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X$-homomorphisms $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X\to j^\ast\mathscr{I}$.

That is, the Baer's criterion seems to be correct if demanded relative to every open subset of $X$.
To get the "only if", we must record that the usual adjunction $j_!\dashv j^\ast$ can be modified to an adjunction between module categories. Specifically, if $j_{(!)}$ is the usual functor, $(j_{(!)}\mathscr{F})(V):=\{\sigma\in\mathscr{F}(V\cap U)\,|\,\mathrm{supp}(\sigma)\text{ is closed in }V\}$, then define $j_!:\mathfrak{Mod}(j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X)\to\mathfrak{Mod}(\mathcal{O}_X)$ via $j_!\mathscr{F}:=j_{(!)}\mathscr{F}\otimes_{j_{(!)}j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_X$. Notice $j_{(!)}j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X$ is not a sheaf of rings, just a sheaf of nonunital rings; this is fine, the tensor product still makes sense and is well-behaved.
EDIT: while the above paragraph is correct, it is also silly. There is a natural way to view $j_{(!)}\mathscr{F}$ as a $\mathcal{O}_X$-module, and $j_{(!)}\mathscr{F}\cong j_{(!)}\mathscr{F}\otimes_{j_{(!)}j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X}\mathcal{O}_X$ naturally as modules. Indeed if $x\in j_{(!)}\mathscr{F}(V),s\in\mathcal{O}_X(V)$ then $sx$ is defined as $s|_{V\cap U}\cdot x\in\mathscr{F}(V\cap U)$ which has support contained in the support of $x$, so has proper support.
I have personally checked $j_!$ is left adjoint to $j^\ast$ in the module categories. It is also true that $j_!$ is exact. Therefore, $j^\ast$ maps injective $\mathcal{O}_X$-modules to injective $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X$ modules. Also notice that while in general, $j^\ast$ for modules categories is different to $j^\ast$ for sheaves on a space, in the case of $j$ an open immersion they are the same thing i.e. just restriction to $U$.
We may proceed as in my question, with $U$ being the same thing. One small remark about Zorning carefully; if $B$ is a sheaf, $A$ a subpresheaf, then the sheafification map $A\to A'$ is injective, a subset inclusion. We don't actually need to demand $\sigma$ is inextensible, though we may do this if we wish by another application of Zorn's lemma and the gluing axiom.
There is a multiplication-by-$\sigma$ map $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X\to j^\ast(P)\to j^\ast(P/\mathcal{H})\to j^\ast(\mathcal{H'}/\mathcal{H})$ which, since sheafification preserves stalks, is clearly an epimorphism of $j^\ast\mathcal{O}_X$ modules. Let $\mathfrak{a}$ be its kernel. Minor subtlety; $P/\mathcal{H}$ is a quotient of presheaves, $\mathcal{H'}/\mathcal{H}$ is to be the quotient in the sense of sheaves.
There is a map $\lambda:\mathfrak{a}\to j^\ast\mathscr{I}$ which takes a section $s\in\mathfrak{a}(V)$ to $\phi'(s\cdot\sigma|_V)$. This is well defined, since $s\cdot\sigma|_V$ is the image of $s$ in $j^\ast(P)\subseteq j^\ast(\mathcal{H}')$ and it is killed by the quotient i.e. (be slightly careful with that, mixing presehaves and sheaves) lands in $\mathcal{H}$, so that $\phi'$ is defined.
By hypothesis, there results a section $\gamma\in\mathscr{I}(U)$ so that $s\cdot\gamma|_V=\phi'(s\cdot\sigma|_V)$ whenever $s\in\mathfrak{a}(V)$. Now consider the map of presheaves $\kappa:P\to\mathscr{I}$: $$\kappa|_V(x):=\begin{cases}\phi'(x)&V\not\subseteq U\\\phi'(y)+s\cdot\gamma|_V&V\subseteq U,\,x=y+s\cdot\sigma|_V\end{cases}$$Is this well-defined? It's obviously linear and a $\mathscr{O}_X$-module map if so. Should $x=y+s\cdot\sigma|_V=y'+s'\cdot\sigma|_V$ happen then $(s-s')\cdot\sigma|_V\in\mathcal{H}$ and $s-s'\in\mathfrak{a}(V)$ happens. Consequently: $$\phi'(y)+s\cdot\gamma|_V-(\phi'(y')+s'\cdot\gamma|_V)=-\phi'((s-s')\cdot\sigma|_V)+(s-s')\cdot\gamma|_V=0$$
By the universal property of sheafification, $\kappa$ extends along $P\hookrightarrow\mathcal{H'}$ to some $\phi'':\mathcal{H'}\to\mathscr{I}$ which indeed extends $\phi$, and we are done.
